# has_one :through association error: Cannot have a has_one :through association where the :through association is a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have the models `Subscription`, `SubscriptionCart` and `Invoice`. A subscription `has_many` `:subscription_carts`, and a subscription_cart `has_many` `:invoices`.

I need to associate a `Subscription` with an `Invoice` of `scheduled` status of which each `SubscriptionCart` has only one (that relation already exists).

subscription:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  has_many    :subscription_carts
end
```

subscription_cart:

```
class SubscriptionCart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  has_many   :invoices, as: :invoiceable
  has_one    :scheduled_invoice, -> { scheduled }, class_name: :Invoice,
                                                   inverse_of: :invoiceable,
                                                   as: :invoiceableh
end
```

invoice:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoiceable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I tried with the following statement in the Subscription model:

```
has_one     :scheduled_invoice, through: :subscription_carts, source: :scheduled_invoice
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have
> a has_one :through association 'Subscription#scheduled_invoice' where
> the :through association 'Subscription#subscription_carts' is a
> collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the
> :through option instead.

I don't fully understand what the error is telling me nor the suggestion it's giving me.

I've also tried `has_one     :scheduled_invoice, -> { scheduled.ordered_by_due_date }, through: :subscription_carts, class_name: "Invoice"` with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're not showing it in the Invoice class; assuming `scheduled` is a key in an `enum status` in Invoice.

You can leverage the use of scopes to achieve what you require:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :invoiceable, polymorphic: true
 enum status: [:scheduled, :archived], _suffix: invoice
end
```

And then you could `subscription_cart.invoices.scheduled_invoice` to fetch the scheduled invoice belonging to that subscription_cart.

( You can also remove the suffix if the syntax becomes redudant. )

Scopes are pretty powerful in rails, its worth taking a look at them --> https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Comment: Thanks. We use scopes in the Invoice model to fetch invoices with a certain status. Please note that a Subscription has_many SubscriptionCart. I tried something like `has_one :scheduled_invoice, -> subscription_carts.authorized.last.scheduled_invoice}` but I'm getting a `NameError: uninitialized constant Subscription::ScheduledInvoice` error.

Comment: That's because the scope `scheduled_invoice` belongs to the Invoice collection not the subscription model. 

scopes the belong to Invoice can only be used like `subscription_carts.authorized.last.invoices.scheduled_invoice`